# Low Screen Resolution on SLES 11.3 KVM guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, sles11, display, screen-resolution

I have a SLES 11.3 guest running on KVM on an Ubuntu 14.04 host.  When I installed the OS, I selected 'vga' as the QEMU display type.

Now that the guest is up and running I cannot change the display beyond the default 800x600 resolution.

SaX2 utility reports the card as "VESA Framebuffer Graphics" and the monitor as "VESA 800x600@60HZ".

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to QXL and Spice, you'll get as high a resolution as you like

Comment: SLES 11.3 as a guest doesn't support Spice/QXL. It wasn't supported until SLES 12.

Comment: wasn't aware of that... one more reason not to use SLES IMO.